# Can't open .kproj projects in VS .NET 2013 Update 4?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I cloned an ASP.NET vNext project from github and I'm running VS .NET 2013.  I was under the impression that Update 4 would allow me to open vNext projects with .kproj files, but I'm getting the following message:

> Unsupported This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the
>   following projects. The project types may not be installed or this
>   version of Visual Studio may not support them.

Is there something else I need to do in .NET 2013 to open a .kproj project? I'd like to avoid 2015 if I can help it.

Comment: You need to run Visual Studio 2015 Preview. See [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-preview-vs#ASP) for more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ASP.NET vNext is only supported in VS 2015.

You cannot open kproj files in a previous version

Comment: More info about `.kproj` exists here: http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/asp-vnext-kproj